# How to iterate over HashMap starting from given key?

Tags: rust, hashmap

Given a HashMap of `n` elements how does one start iteration from `n-x` element.

The order of elements does not matter, the only problem I need to solve is to start iteration from given key.

Example:

```
let mut map: HashMap<&str, i32> = HashMap::new();
map.insert("one", 1);
map.insert("two", 2);
map.insert("three", 3);
map.insert("four", 4);
[...]

for (k, v) in map {
    //how to start iteration from third item and not the first one
}
```

Tried to google it but no examples found so far.

Comment: HashMap is unordered, there is no meaning to iteration "starting from a given key". It can cover from nothing to the whole map.

Comment: Do you want to maintain insertion order, or sorted order?

Comment: If you need ordering, you probably want an array or vector. If each element is compound, then it would be an array or vector of structs. Maybe you could describe the broader issue you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Tried to google it but no examples found so far.

That's because as Chayim Friedman notes it doesn't really make sense, a hashmap has an essentially random internal order, which means it has an arbitrary iteration order. Iterating from or between keys (/ entries) thus doesn't make much sense.

So it sounds a lot like an XY problem, what is the reason why you're trying to iterate "starting from a given key"?

Though if you really want that, you can just use the [`skip_while`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip_while) adapter, and skip while you have not found the key you're looking for.

Alternatively, since your post is ambiguous (you talk about both key and position) you can use the [`skip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip) adapter to skip over a fixed number of items.

Technically neither will start iterating from that entry, they'll both start iterating from 0 but will only yield items following the specified break point. The standard library's hashmap has no support for range iteration (because that doesn't really make any sense on hashmap), and its iterators are not random access either (for similar reason).

Comment: On top of that, even making use either of these methods to  `skip`, neither the issued items nor their order will be fixed from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a [BTreeMap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html), which has sorted keys and a [range function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.range) which iterates over a range of keys.

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map = BTreeMap::new();
    map.insert(1, "one");
    map.insert(2, "two");
    map.insert(3, "three");
    for (&key, &value) in map.range(2..) {
        println!("{key}: {value}");
    }
}

// 2: two
// 3: three
```